# MySQL Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, error-code, mysql-error-1193

Ok so i'm working on triggers, and it tells me it(MySQL workbench 5.2) doesn't recognize this variable.
***Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable error_msg_3***

I think it would be correct using it in a trigger, please help me

```
CREATE TRIGGER controlla_MaxCARDINALITA_INSERT
BEFORE INSERT ON SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN

DECLARE max_cardinalita INTEGER;
DECLARE error_msg_3 CONDITION FOR SQLSTATE '99003';

SELECT COUNT(*) into max_cardinalita
FROM SENTIERO__HA__TAPPA
WHERE IDsentiero=NEW.IDsentiero;

IF max_cardinalita>=10 THEN
        SIGNAL error_msg_3;
        SET error_msg_3='INSERT: Il sentiero ha già il massimo numero di tappe consentito';

END IF;

END$$
```

**EDIT ::**

I tried this, and it seems working

```
DECLARE msg VARCHAR(255);
set msg = concat('MyTriggerError: Trying to insert a negative value in trigger_test: ');
signal sqlstate '45000' set message_text = msg;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_unknown_system_variable), the error `#1193` occurs when you use wrong code for `SQLSTATE`.

> **Message**: Unknown system variable <kbd>%s</kbd>

And, as you can see on the same [page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-error-reference.html), the SQLSTATE `99003` is not defined.

Comment: please see my edit, why does that code work? there isn't 45000 in the table, i think

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana Please again, refer to the docs on usage of [`SIGNAL`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html) clause. It clearly mentions: **SIGNAL is the way to “return” an error. SIGNAL provides error information to a handler, to an outer portion of the application, or to the client. To signal a generic SQLSTATE value, use '45000', which means _unhandled user-defined exception_.**

Comment: Thanks, last question for you: mysql doesn't let me using multiple triggers for the same event and action time for one table... so i heared about functions and procedures; are them the solution? I'd like to solve it in the easiest way, i'm in hurry. Thanks

Comment: @Jimmy5nomana For that, you'd get better advices over at [DBA stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: That's not theory!!! if you have 3 triggers as these: AFTER UPDATE ON TABLE 1... how could they run on that table?