# Declaring and setting variables to test difference between SP and query

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, procedure

I am trying to solve another problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14794011/why-does-query-give-different-result-once-put-into-stored-procedure). I was told by a member that in order to find an answer to my problem I needed to change the query to match the SP. In order to do that I was told to declare variables so I am using variables like I am in the SP. my problem is I have read so much my eyes are hurting and I cannot figure out how to declare friggin variables.

Please help!!

This is what I have read so far:

[resource 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1102109/mysql-delimiter-syntax-errors),
[resource 2](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?104,72508,72508),
[resource 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678934/mysql-error-code-1193-unknown-system-variable), [resource 4](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-statement.html), [resource 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009954/mysql-variable-vs-variable-whats-the-difference)

and I could go on an on. I am literally stuck. I am new to SQL and this is bugging me out. I do not have to use a SP but I would really like to so I can learn the dos and donts and hopefully learn enough to help others.

```
DECLARE zipcode VARCHAR(30)
DECLARE radius VARCHAR(30)
SET zipcode = 08360
SET radius = 50

SELECT C.CustomerName, C.MenuId
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ZIPCODE, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( (
    SELECT Z.LAT
    FROM ZipCodes Z
    WHERE Z.ZIPCODE =zipcode
    LIMIT 0 , 1
    ) ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LAT ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LNG ) - RADIANS( (

      SELECT Z.LNG
      FROM ZipCodes Z
      WHERE Z.ZIPCODE =zipcode
      LIMIT 0 , 1
    ) ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( (

    SELECT Z.LAT
    FROM ZipCodes Z
    WHERE Z.ZIPCODE =zipcode
    LIMIT 0 , 1
  ) ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( LAT ) ) ) ) AS distance
  FROM ZipCodes
  HAVING distance <radius
  ORDER BY distance
) AS RelevantCodes ON ( C.ZIPCODE = RelevantCodes.ZIPCODE )
```

I have tried so many combinations from what I have seen on the internet that I am starting to think its just too late in the night to do anything more. If you take a look at some of the resources I looked at you will see where I saw the difference between with '@' and without.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a stored proc, you'll need to use the proper syntax.

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-procedure.html
Note that inside the proc body you'll need to terminate each and every statement with a `;`.

Because you'll need to let MySQL know when the body proc ends and you'll need to redeclare the delimiter into something that not a `;`.
This will prevent MySQL from interpreting your stored proc after the first ';', but instead listen all the way up to the `$$`.

Don't forget to revert the delimiter back to the default after you're done inputting the function.

```
SET DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE QueryCustomerMenu(IN zipcode VARCHAR(30), IN radius VARCHAR(30))
BEGIN

DECLARE somevar VARCHAR(20);
SET somevar = '456';

SELECT C.CustomerName, C.MenuId
FROM Customers C
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT ZIPCODE, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS( (
    SELECT Z.LAT
    FROM ZipCodes Z
    WHERE Z.ZIPCODE =zipcode
    LIMIT 0 , 1
    ) ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LAT ) ) * COS( RADIANS( LNG ) - RADIANS( (

      SELECT Z.LNG
      FROM ZipCodes Z
      WHERE Z.ZIPCODE =zipcode
      LIMIT 0 , 1
    ) ) ) + SIN( RADIANS( (

    SELECT Z.LAT
    FROM ZipCodes Z
    WHERE Z.ZIPCODE =zipcode
    LIMIT 0 , 1
  ) ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( LAT ) ) ) ) AS distance
  FROM ZipCodes
  HAVING distance <radius
  ORDER BY distance
) AS RelevantCodes ON ( C.ZIPCODE = RelevantCodes.ZIPCODE );

END $$

SET DELIMITER ;
```

Now you can call the stored proc with:

```
CALL QueryCustomerMenu('09210','20');
```

And it will return a resultset with the `CustomerName` and `MenuID`'s.

Comment: This explains why I could not get the variables declared. Thank a lot! for my query.