# Error Code: 1193. Unknown system variable 'sys_time_in_current_table'

Tags: mysql, sql, workbench

i am getting following error, while i have tried on google,but didn't find the solution.
Mysql workbench version is 6.2;
Mysql version is 5.6.21.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`developer`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_tr069_update_performance_performanceinventory_test`(
 in temp_db varchar(256),
 in nocout_db varchar(256)
)
BEGIN
    declare sys_time_in_current_table int ;    
    declare sys_time_in_perf_inventory_status int;

    set @temporary_query = concat('set sys_time_in_current_table = (select sys_timestamp from ',temp_db,'.','performance_performanceinventory limit 1 )');
    PREPARE stmt from @temporary_query;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;



    set @temporary_query1 = concat('set sys_time_in_perf_inventory_status = (select sys_timestamp from ',nocout_db,'.performance_inventorystatus order by id desc limit 1) ;');
    PREPARE stmt1 from @temporary_query1;
    EXECUTE stmt1;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;


   set @temporary_query=NULL;    
    -- set @temporary_query=concat();    
    -- prepare stmt from ;  
    select `sys_time_in_current_table`,`sys_time_in_perf_inventory_status`;

    IF `sys_time_in_current_table`>`sys_time_in_perf_inventory_status`
    THEN
        select 1;
        set @temporary_query2 =
        concat('UPDATE ', nocout_db,'.`performance_inventorystatus` inv_status
        INNER JOIN ', temp_db,'.`performance_performanceinventory` perf_inv on  
        inv_status.device_name=perf_inv.device_name and
        inv_status.service_name=perf_inv.service_name and 
        inv_status.data_source=perf_inv.data_source 
        SET
            inv_status.device_name=perf_inv.`device_name` ,
            inv_status.service_name=perf_inv.`service_name` ,
            inv_status.machine_name=perf_inv.`machine_name` ,
            inv_status.site_name=perf_inv.`site_name` ,
            inv_status.ip_address=perf_inv.`ip_address` ,
            inv_status.data_source=perf_inv.`data_source` ,
            inv_status.severity=perf_inv.`severity` ,
            inv_status.current_value=perf_inv.`current_value` ,
            inv_status.min_value=perf_inv.`min_value` ,
            inv_status.max_value=perf_inv.`max_value` ,
            inv_status.avg_value=perf_inv.`avg_value` ,
            inv_status.warning_threshold=perf_inv.`warning_threshold` ,
            inv_status.critical_threshold=perf_inv.`critical_threshold` ,
            inv_status.sys_timestamp=perf_inv.`sys_timestamp` ,
            inv_status.check_timestamp=perf_inv.`check_timestamp`;') ;

        PREPARE stmt2 from @temporary_query2;
        EXECUTE stmt2;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt2;


      set @temporary_query3 =   concat('INSERT INTO ',nocout_db,'.`performance_inventorystatus`
        (
        `device_name`,
        `service_name`,
        `machine_name`,
        `site_name`,
        `ip_address`,
        `data_source`,
        `severity`,
        `current_value`,
        `min_value`,
        `max_value`,
        `avg_value`,
        `warning_threshold`,
        `critical_threshold`,
        `sys_timestamp`,
        `check_timestamp`)
        SELECT 
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`device_name`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`service_name`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`machine_name`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`site_name`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`ip_address`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`data_source`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`severity`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`current_value`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`min_value`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`max_value`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`avg_value`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`warning_threshold`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`critical_threshold`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`sys_timestamp`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`check_timestamp`
        FROM ', temp_db,'.`performance_performanceinventory`
        left join ', nocout_db,'.performance_inventorystatus inv_status on 
        performance_performanceinventory.device_name=inv_status.device_name and
        performance_performanceinventory.service_name=inv_status.service_name and 
        performance_performanceinventory.data_source=inv_status.data_source 
        where inv_status.device_name is null ;');

        PREPARE stmt3 from @temporary_query3;
        EXECUTE stmt3;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt3;


      set @temporary_query4 =   concat('INSERT INTO', nocout_db,'.`performance_performanceinventory`
        (
        `device_name`,
        `service_name`,
        `machine_name`,
        `site_name`,
        `ip_address`,
        `data_source`,
        `severity`,
        `current_value`,
        `min_value`,
        `max_value`,
        `avg_value`,
        `warning_threshold`,
        `critical_threshold`,
        `sys_timestamp`,
        `check_timestamp`)
        SELECT 
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`device_name`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`service_name`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`machine_name`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`site_name`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`ip_address`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`data_source`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`severity`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`current_value`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`min_value`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`max_value`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`avg_value`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`warning_threshold`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`critical_threshold`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`sys_timestamp`,
            `performance_performanceinventory`.`check_timestamp`
        FROM ', temp_db,'.`performance_performanceinventory` ;');

    PREPARE stmt4 from @temporary_query4;
    EXECUTE stmt4;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt4;

      set @temporary_query5 =  concat('Truncate ', temp_db,'.`performance_performanceinventory`');
    PREPARE stmt5 from @temporary_query5;
    EXECUTE stmt5;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt5;

    END IF;

END
```

When i execute this stored procedure,then its done ....
but its throwing run time error when i call this procedure....

```
call nocout_bhutan_testing.sp_tr069_update_performance_performanceinventory_test('tr069_temp_machine_1', 'nocout_bhutan_testing');
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14678934/mysql-error-code-1193-unknown-system-variable

Comment: @VirendraNagda..i looked at this,but its not a solution for my issue