# phpMyAdmin in palapa web server won't work

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I downloaded `palapa web server` on my Infinix Hot 2 but had problems configuring `phpmyadmin`. So I downloaded `phpmyadmin` using `KSWEB` and copied the folder to `/pws/phpmyadmin` and `phpmyadmin` started working. However, now I am having a problem with logging in to `phpmyadmin` on `http:// 127.0.0.1:9999/phpmyadmin`. When I use `root` as user and blank password, it gives me this error:

```
 #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

If I try using `root` as user and `adminadmin` as password as instructed by `palapa web server` website, I get the following:

```
Error

SQL query: Edit Edit

SET lc_messages = 'en_US';

MySQL said: Documentation

#1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'
```

I will be grateful for any help to get `phpmyadmin` running smoothly in `pws`.

Comment: Why you have selected android tag for this question

Comment: sorry, my bad :) any help on the question?

Comment: to me, the first error, is because root with blank password either not exist, or not allowed from 127.0.0.1, second try with `adminadmin` is the correct way, now the second error is your actual issue, though i am not sure what it is.

Comment: have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084464/1193-unknown-system-variable-lc-messages-when-trying-to-login-to-phpmyadmin

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'll try out Gerald's answer of downloading an older version of `phpmyadmin` which is compatible with my `pws`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`lc_messages` is a variable that was introduced in MySQL 5.5, it replaces the old `language` commands ([see release notes](http://downloads.mysql.com/docs/mysql-5.5-relnotes-en.a4.pdf)).

[Palapa Web Server](http://alfanla.com/palapa-web-server/), on the other hand, ships with MySQL 5.1, where this variable doesn't exist yet, hence the error messages.

Download the right version of phpMyAdmin [from the web site](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/), currently version 4.0.10.17, which doesn't need MySQL 5.5 (the required versions are listed there).

Using this older version that matches your other components should fix the problem.

Comment: Note: From what I gather from the Palapa website you should be able to install phpmyadmin from the Palapa control app itself. That should be a matching version that just works.

Comment: I tried install from the app but it always have me the following error: `Install failed with error: http://downloads.sourceforge.net/project/phpmyadmin/phpMyAdmin/4.1.14.1/phpMyAdmin-4.1.14.1-english.zip?download&failedmirror=jaist.dl.sourceforge.net`. So should I download `phpMyAdmin-4.1.14.1-english.zip` or version 4.0.10.17?

Comment: You have to download a version that is compatible to your versions of PHP and MySQL. According to the documentation that would be the version 4.0.

Comment: I downloaded `phpmyadmin-4.1.14.1-english.zip` and it worked. thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Version php == version mysql
Check version

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).