# WAMPServer Install - Error on phpMyAdmin login - Error #1193

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to set up WAMPServer for the first time on my personal computer to do some WordPress work. When I try to log into phpadmin with the root login, I get an error screen. The Error reads as such:

> SQL query: Edit
>
> SET lc_messages = 'en_US';
>
> MySQL said:
>
> 1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'

I've tried running PHP version 7.0.10 and 5.6.25 but the errors occurred on both.

I'm running MySQL version 5.7.14

I've tried looking at a StackOverflow forum with the same issue, linked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084464/1193-unknown-system-variable-lc-messages-when-trying-to-login-to-phpmyadmin), but none of the suggested fixes worked for me there, since I'm running a pretty updated version of phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct name for that parameter is `lc-messages` note a hyphen and not an underscore.

Have you amended anything in the 'my.ini'?

**RE: Your Comment**

Then potentially you have another MySQL runing or maybe just a rouge `my.ini` file on your system.

Search for `my.ini` and if you find it anywhere other then inside the `\wamp\` or `\wamp64\` folders, remove or rename it. There should not be one outside the wamp folder structure.

Comment: No, I've only downloaded WAMPServer and put WordPress into a folder on the www directory.

Comment: See amended answer

Comment: I had to restart the computer after changing the name of a my.ini file that I found for the changes to take effect. After that, it's working! Thanks!

Comment: You are Welcome. You could have just restarted MYSQL using the wampmanager menus `wampmanager->MYSQL-> Service Administrator->restart service`

Comment: I have another my.ini on my system  C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0

Comment: @SumanpalSinghSaggu That means you probably also have another MySQL Server running. To avoid confusion I would uninstall that other MySQL Server. **But remember to backup any databases that exist in that server before you uninstall it**

Comment: I think this is installed by MS SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO,  I have to keep both the servers. Any solution plz.

Comment: MS SQL MANAGEMENT STUDIO is a tool for managing SQLServer and not MySQL

Answer (score 0):

**Worked for me**

On my system there was **another SQL SERVER** was running, that was the problem.

Simply go to WAMPMANAGER-> MySQL-> Use a port other than 3306

(In my case, Wamp Manager automatically selected port 3308)

click ok and restart the wamp server.