# phpMyAdmin version for PHP 7.2 + mySQL 5.0

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I had PHP 5.6 + mySQL 5.0 installed on my Linux server, and everything worked ok with an old version of phpMyAdmin.

However, I was updgraded to PHP 7.2 (mySQL 5.0 still installed) and such old version phpMyAdmin stopped working. I tried with the last versions of phpMyAdmin and I receive error messages such as:

> #1193 - Unknown system variable 'lc_messages'

I wondered if there is an intermediate version of phpMyAdmin which still works with PHP 7.2 + mySQL 5.0. Thank you!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38084464/1193-unknown-system-variable-lc-messages-when-trying-to-login-to-phpmyadmin

Comment: or just install new php my admin that is compatible with php 7

Comment: Your database is a decade out of date. There is no excuse for that. Fix it.